# IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, range, indexoutofrangeexception

While stumbling my way through a tutorial, I've had a recurring issue (I say recurring, because it seemed to spontaneously resolve itself after I'd given up for the day and later on begin appearing again, I don't know what I did to make that happen) with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "roguelike.py", line 215, in <module>
    make_map()
  File "roguelike.py", line 131, in make_map
    create_room(new_room)
  File "roguelike.py", line 84, in create_room
    map[x][y].blocked = False
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Relevant code below:

```
def create_room(room):
    global map
    #set all tiles inside the room to passable
    for x in range(room.x1 + 1, room.x2):
        for y in range(room.y1 + 1, room.y2):
            map[x][y].blocked = False
            map[x][y].block_sight = False
```

It ended up at the point where I was comparing the code I had written character-by-character to the example code written in the tutorial, with no luck. This is the first time 'map' is used in the program, and I'm pretty lost when it comes to lists in python.

As a final note, I've poked about through other questions in the same spirit, but I couldn't apply them to my situation due to my limited knowledge.

Comment: Honestly, I would steer clear of any tutorial that uses variable names like `map` (which shadows the built-in function `map()`).

Comment: Out of interest what is the tutorial? I have seen so many Python questions with maps and rooms here.

Comment: If you want an answer, I think you need to add some context here.  What is map?  How big is it supposed to be?  What does the rest of this tutorial do?  A link to the tutorial would probably be helpful too.  Solely based on what you've posted, it's hard to give you a useful answer.

Comment: @MrE, This http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_python%2Blibtcod is the tutorial I'm working with.

Comment: @BrentNash This http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_python%2Blibtcod,_part_3_code#Dungeon_generator is a link to the code up to the point I'm at, with the code in question being directly after class assignment.

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: No way to help without seeing how `map` is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atleast one of `room.x1 + 1`, `room.x2`, `room.y1 + 1` and `room.y2` exceeds your map. Either check your map size or limit the access.

Option 1:

```
class RoomOutsideError(Exception):
    pass

# ...

def create_room(room):
    global map
    #set all tiles inside the room to passable

    # check for limits and raise exception
    #    (this will need handling outside this function)
    max_x, max_y = len(map) - 1, len(max[0]) - 1
    if room.x1+1 > max_x or room.x2 > max_x or \
       room.y1+1 > max_y or room.y2 > max_y:
           raise RoomOutsideError("Room outside map.")

    for x in range(room.x1 + 1, room.x2):
        for y in range(room.y1 + 1, room.y2):
            map[x][y].blocked = False
            map[x][y].block_sight = False
```

Option 2:

```
def create_room(room):
    global map
    #set all tiles inside the room to passable

    # limit room coordinates. This is free of additional handlings but
    # might create odd rooms in the corner of the map.
    max_x, max_y = len(map) - 1, len(map[0]) - 1
    for x in range(room.x1 + 1, room.x2):
        for y in range(room.y1 + 1, room.y2):
            map[min(max_x, x)][min(max_y, y)].blocked = False
            map[min(max_x, x)][min(max_y, y)].block_sight = False
```